# Length of matrix diagonals

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, algebra-precalculus

I would like to compute the length of each diagonal of a matrix.

I use the following index for diagonals:

- $0$ for the main diagonal;
- negative indices for sub-diagonals;
- positive indices for super-diagonals.

Here is an example:

$$
\begin{array}{rccccc}
\small 0 & &  \small 1 & \small 2 & \small 3 & \small 4 \\
& a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14}  & a_{15} \\
\small -1 & a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}  & a_{25} \\
\small -2 & a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34}  & a_{35}
\end{array}
$$
The first sub-diagonal has the index $-1$ and is equal to ${\begin{pmatrix} a_{21} & a_{32}\end{pmatrix}}^T$.

Let $A$ be a $n \times m$ matrix, let $d_k$ be the length of the $k$th diagonal of $A$ with $k \in [\![ -(n-1) ; m-1 ]\!]$.
How can I compute $d_k$?

I have a solution but it involves numerous tests:

```
GD = max({n,m}), LD = min({n,m}).
RD = GD-LD.
If LD = n then
   If k < 0 then
     dk = LD - |k|
   Else
     If k < RD+1
       dk = LD
     Else
       dk = LD - (k-RD)
     End if
   End if
Else
   If k < 0 then
     If |k| < RD+1
       dk = LD
     Else
       dk = LD - (|k|-RD)
     End if
   Else
     dk = LD - k
   End if
End if
```

I was wondering if there is a trick to avoid some of those tests or if it exists a more direct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $d_k=\min({m,n,m-k,n+k)}$?

Comment: Brilliant! That's the proper way to do it!